# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException nextDouble() error?

Tags: java

#### CitireFisier.java

```
public class CitireFisier  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("fisier.txt");

        Scanner scn = null;
        try {
            scn = new Scanner(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int size = scn.nextInt();  
        System.out.println("val  is " + size);

        double var  = scn.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("val  is " + var);
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
val is 3
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
```

#### fisier.txt

```
3
0.1 0.7 0.2 init g
0.0 0.0 1.0 g y
0.0 0.0 1.0 g y
```

`nextDouble()` receive the error but 0.1 is `double`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your locale uses comma as the decimal separator, then 0.1 is not a double.

To fix this, instantiate your Scanner like so:

```
 scn = new Scanner(f).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Yes, this is a wise answer. French, German, and Italian uses a comma, and this will break when using those locales.

Comment: Thanks!  it works with  scn = new Scanner(f).useLocale(Locale.US);

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problems depends on the Java version used, because in my Java Version (Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)), I don't get the error. Nevertheless, maybe this helps for your version (as mentioned in the question's comments):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("fisier.txt");
    Scanner scn = null;
    try {
        scn = new Scanner(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int size = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("val  is " + size);

    // not needed in my Java Version
    scn.nextLine();

    double var = scn.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("val  is " + var);
}
```

**EDIT**:

You may also want to look at [Trouble using nextInt and nextLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089522/trouble-using-nextint-and-nextline)